# Install Stripe CLI on Laravel Sail so that it can be used from within the command line in a devcontainer

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-sail

I would like to be able to use the [Stripe CLI](https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-cli) from within the [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/sail) terminal, meaning that I'd like to be able to issue commands such as `sail strip login` or, even better, just `stripe login` from within a [Devcontainer](https://laravel.com/docs/sail#using-devcontainers) terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a Laravel project with Sail installed and working:

## Step 1

Publish the Dockerfile of Laravel Sail following the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/sail#sail-customization) by running `sail artisan sail:publish` or `php artisan sail:publish` depending on your context

## Step 2

In your project root, there will now be a `docker` folder. Navigate to the php version specified in your `docker-compose.yaml` file which is also in the project root.

Locate `&& apt-get update \` and replace with the following:

```
    && curl -sS https://packages.stripe.dev/api/security/keypair/stripe-cli-gpg/public | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/stripe.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/stripe.gpg] https://packages.stripe.dev/stripe-cli-debian-local stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stripe.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y stripe \
```

## Step 3

Run the command `sail build --no-cache` or otherwise rebuild your container (ie: from the Deccontainer menu in VS Code, Storm etc)

## Step 4

You will now be able to issue commands such as `sail stripe login` or even `stripe login` if you're using a Devcontainer terminal.